# memory usage export from database to csv in php

Tags: php, mysql, export, memory-management

I need to export data from mysql to csv. I have to select data from several tables putting them in arrays, then process them and return them to browser as .csv. 
I noticed that arrays consume huge ammount of rows.
For example, I imported a .csv in the database which is 1.8M, then I try to export this data from the database in .csv. The memory_get_peak_usage() shows more than 128M to store arrays with data.

For example this small array takes more than 700 bytes:

```
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();  
        //get constant fields of the subscriber
        $data = array(array('subscriber_id' => 1315444, 'email_address' => 'test0@gmail.com',
                            'first_name' => 'Michael', 'last_name' => 'Allen'));
        echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory;
```

So exporting even several megabytes of data, require hundreds megabytes of memory in php script.
Is there a way to solve this problem? 
Tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `subscribers` (
     `subscriber_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `list_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `email_address` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `first_name` varchar(50) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
     `last_name` varchar(50) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
     `ip` int(10) unsigned default NULL COMMENT '\nThe ip address of the subscriber that we can get when he opens the \nthe email or subscribe using subsribe form.\nTheoretically it can be used to segment by Location (which is not correct if someone uses proxy).',
     `preferred_format` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Preferred format of \n0 - HTML, \n1 -Text,\n2 - Mobile',
     `state` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1' COMMENT '1 - subscribed\n2 - unsubscribed\n3 - cleaned\n4 - not confirmed, it means the user subscribed but has not confirmed it yet.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n',
     `cause_of_cleaning` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT '\nThis field is the cause of moving the subscriber to the \n0 - not used\n1 - spam complaint\n2 - hard bounce\n3 - several soft bounces',
     `date_added` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'The data when the subscriber was added. I suppose this field can be used in the conditions forming the segment',
     `last_changed` datetime NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`subscriber_id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `email_list_id` (`email_address`,`list_id`),
     KEY `FK_list_id` (`list_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `FK_list_id` FOREIGN KEY (`list_id`) REFERENCES `lists` (`list_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
    CREATE TABLE `subscribers_multivalued` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `subscriber_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `field_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `value` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '\nThe identifier of the account',
     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
     KEY `subscriber_fk` (`subscriber_id`),
     KEY `field_fk` (`field_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `field_fk_string_multivalued` FOREIGN KEY (`field_id`) REFERENCES `custom_fields` (`field_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT `subscriber_fk_multivalued` FOREIGN KEY (`subscriber_id`) REFERENCES `subscribers` (`subscriber_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
CREATE TABLE `subscribers_custom_data_string` (
 `subscriber_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `field_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `value` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '\nThe identifier of the account',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`subscriber_id`,`field_id`),
 KEY `subscriber_fk` (`subscriber_id`),
 KEY `field_fk` (`field_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `field_fk_string` FOREIGN KEY (`field_id`) REFERENCES `custom_fields` (`field_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `subscriber_fk_string` FOREIGN KEY (`subscriber_id`) REFERENCES `subscribers` (`subscriber_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

There are other tables for fields similar to the table with strings for numbers, dates. For them primary key is subscriber_id, field_id.

When query fails (for example we have several custom fields):

SELECT `subscribers`.`email_address`, `subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`,
GROUP_CONCAT(t1.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Colors, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Languages
FROM `subscribers`
LEFT JOIN `subscribers_multivalued` AS `t1` ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id AND t1.field_id=112
LEFT JOIN `subscribers_multivalued` AS `t2` ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t2.subscriber_id AND t2.field_id=111
WHERE (list_id=40)
GROUP BY `subscribers`.`email_address`, `subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`

It would return this:

test1000@gmail.com      Michelle    Bush    Red|Red|Blue|Blue   English|Spanish|English|Spanish instead of
test1000@gmail.com      Michelle    Bush    Red|Blue
English|Spanish

Thank you for any information.

Comment: This is certainly because you're loading the entire resultset from your MySQL quesries into PHP arrays that reside in PHP memory before writing it to CSV. If it's possible to restructure your code so that you're loading only a single result into memory at a time before writing that row to csv, then looping to fetch the next result, this should be a lot lower memory use.

Comment: Knowing the details of your database structures, and the data processing that you do before building the csv line, we might be able to suggest ways of optimising this so that it can be processed a row at a time

Comment: I export data that only takes several megabytes in .csv, but in array of php they consume huge ammount of memory. I need to get data from several tables to export them. I export data from EAV, I select data from table with entity (email, first and last name) and then I select values of custom fields. Then I process this data and put in one array and return to browser as .csv.

Comment: Almost certainly there are ways of retrieving data from the database and processing it in "chunks", rather than pulling the entirety of your data into PHP memory... but without knowing some details of what you're doing, we can't help in the specifics.

Comment: I store custom fields in several tables related to the main tables, fields of different types are stored in different tables: string_fields, date_fields, number_fields, multivalued_field.

Comment: So what's wrong with doing a single query using JOINs to retrieve the data?

Comment: There is a problem multivalued fields. In this case I'd need to join with temporary table that groups data to make it: value1 | value2 | value3. Such join for rather large amount of data is slow.

Comment: If you can refactor/normalize your multivalued fields, then you'd certainly be able to speed up execution times

Comment: For example, if I have only one multivalued custom field the query would be: SELECT `subscribers`.`email_address`, `subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`, `t1`.`value` AS `Languages` FROM `subscribers` LEFT JOIN (SELECT subscriber_id, field_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '|') AS value FROM subscribers_multivalued WHERE field_id=37 GROUP BY subscriber_id, field_id) AS `t1` ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id AND t1.field_id=37 WHERE (list_id=49) AND (state=1)

Comment: Does SELECT subscribers.email_address, 
    subscribers.first_name, 
    subscribers.last_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(t1.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Languages 
  FROM subscribers 
  LEFT JOIN subscribers_multivalued t1 
   ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id 
    AND t1.field_id=37 
 WHERE (list_id=49) 
   AND (state=1)
; give the same result?

Comment: Yes, if to use one query the problem with performance I see is with multivalued, it seems slow and I don't see a way to optimize it now.

Comment: That's where the SO community can help; but only if we're given enough detail to do so. We can come up with alternatives: you can test if those alternatives are slower or faster, make use of explain to see if they use indexes correctly, etc.

Comment: This is not the same query. Your query would return only one row.

Comment: They are indexes, but for multivalued field, we'd need to JOIN with large temporary tables with grouping, so in this case index can't be used.

Comment: Alright, add the correct group by clause to fix my initial query: SELECT subscribers.email_address, 
    subscribers.first_name, 
    subscribers.last_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(t1.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Languages 
  FROM subscribers 
  LEFT JOIN subscribers_multivalued t1 
   ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id 
    AND t1.field_id=37 
 WHERE (list_id=49) 
   AND (state=1)
 GROUP BY subscribers.email_address, 
    subscribers.first_name, 
    subscribers.last_name
;

Comment: My point is that we can almost certainly reduce your memory usage by optimising your query, especially if the result can be piped directly from MySQL to the csv file, bypassing PHP completely; but we can only come up with alternatives if we know the details of your database structure, and the query result that you're trying to achieve

Comment: There can be several multivalued custom fields.

Comment: The structur is like this: there is tables subscribers it has primary key subscriber_id and constant fields, every subscriber can be custom fields which are in tables dependend on subscribers: subscribers_multivalued, subscribers_string etc. Such table has structure: subscriber_id field_id value. For all such table except multivalued subscriber_id field_id is primary key.

Comment: In subscribers table email field is inique index.

Comment: Please edit your original question post with these table structures (and their indexes), the relationships between them, and the results that you're trying to extract from that data

Comment: I added definitions of the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just the two tables:

Your original query:

```
SELECT subscribers.email_address, 
       subscribers.first_name, 
       subscribers.last_name, 
       t1.value AS Languages 
  FROM subscribers 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT subscriber_id, 
                    field_id, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '|') AS value 
               FROM subscribers_multivalued 
              WHERE field_id=37 
              GROUP BY subscriber_id, field_id
            ) AS t1 
         ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id 
        AND t1.field_id=37 
 WHERE (list_id=49) 
   AND (state=1)
```

gives an explain plan of:

```
id  select_type  table                    type  possible_keys  key         key_len  ref    rows  Extra
1   PRIMARY      subscribers              ref   FK_list_id     FK_list_id  4        const  2     Using where
1   PRIMARY      <derived2>               ALL   NULL           NULL        NULL     NULL   5      
2   DERIVED      subscribers_multivalued  ALL   field_fk       field_fk    4               11    Using filesort
```

My join suggestion:

```
SELECT subscribers.email_address, 
       subscribers.first_name, 
       subscribers.last_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(t1.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Languages 
  FROM subscribers 
  LEFT JOIN subscribers_multivalued t1 
         ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id 
        AND t1.field_id=37 
 WHERE (list_id=49) 
   AND (state=1)
 GROUP BY subscribers.email_address, 
          subscribers.first_name, 
          subscribers.last_name
```

gives an explain plan of:

```
id  select_type  table        type  possible_keys           key            key_len  ref                             rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE       subscribers  ref   FK_list_id              FK_list_id     4        const                           2     Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       t1           ref   subscriber_fk,field_fk  subscriber_fk  4        test.subscribers.subscriber_id  1
```

While I only populated those two tables with a very small volume of data, this suggests to me that my version of the query will execute more efficiently against the database, because it isn't using the derived table that your query generates.

The other tables could be linked into the query in much the same way, and the entire result spooled directly to a csv file rather than parsed further with PHP.

This should give you a run that is both faster and more memory efficient.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT subscribers.email_address, 
       subscribers.first_name, 
       subscribers.last_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Colors, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Languages 
  FROM subscribers 
  LEFT JOIN subscribers_multivalued AS t1 
         ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id 
        AND t1.field_id=112 
  LEFT JOIN subscribers_multivalued AS t2 
    ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t2.subscriber_id 
   AND t2.field_id=37 
 WHERE (list_id=49) 
 GROUP BY subscribers.email_address, 
          subscribers.first_name, 
          subscribers.last_name
```

Note the use of DISTINCT in the GROUP_CONCAT() function

Comment: Thank you vey much, Mark, your query looks like more efficient. I'll try to construct queries like this and to see how much memory the script will consume.

Comment: Test out the full queries using phpmyadmin first. You can easily do an Explain using that, and get a feel for how fast they actually are. But spooling the results directly to csv using freddy K's suggestion should reduce speed significantly (letting MySQL do all the hard work) leaving very little for PHP to actually do besides triggering the export

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with such query, for example if there are both one-valued and multivalued fields the query would be wrong. For example if there are three custom fields: gender (string), langauages and colors (multivalued) the query would be as I added in my post.

Comment: I'm afraid so it's hardly possible to handle without temporary table if to use one query.

Comment: Give me an example of how you're trying to join the other custom fields, and what you expect to get as the result.

Comment: For example, if there two custom fields: langauges and colors and subscriber_id = 1 and emal = test0@gmail.com has colors red, green and languages English, Spanish, Russian I want to have: test0@gmail.com John Jackson red|green English|Spanish|Russian.

Comment: SELECT `subscribers`.`email_address`, `subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Colors, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Languages FROM `subscribers` LEFT JOIN `subscribers_multivalued` AS `t1` ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id AND t1.field_id=112 LEFT JOIN `subscribers_multivalued` AS `t2` ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t2.subscriber_id AND t2.field_id=111 WHERE (list_id=40) GROUP BY `subscribers`.`email_address`, `subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`

Comment: This query would return something like: test1000@gmail.com   Michelle   Bush   Red|Red|Blue|Blue   English|Spanish|English|Spanish, instead of: test1000@gmail.com   Michelle   Bush   Red|Blue   English|Spanish

Comment: I could try to delete superflous data in php fro example transform Red|Red|Blue|Blue to Red|Red|Blue|Blue  beforer putting in .csv, it's rather confusing to me.

Comment: Maybe it's work trying to process one line at a time not to get all array in php.

Comment: I added info at the end of my question.

Comment: It looks like the problem can be solved using DISTINCT expression with aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT as I show in the answer. I'll think about it more but I think it will work.

Answer (score 2):

If possible by your business logic, you could do the transformations in mysql and do a

```
SELECT * from table INTO OUTFILE 'file_name.csv'
```

it has the same options as LOAD DATA INFILE, the file you are writing to must not exist.

Comment: I can't make it because I need data from several tables.

Comment: But you can also join accross tables as well. e.g. `SELECT a.*, b.* from tablea a, tableb b where a.id=b.aid INTO OUTFILE` 'file_name.csv'

Comment: I think I can't make, bause of multivalued fields. In this case I'd need to join with temporary table that groups data to make it: value1 | value2 | value3. Such join for rather large amount of data is slow.

Comment: "Slow" depends on a lot of things: but there are ways in which query execution can often be improved... rather than dismissing this out of hand, why not provide details of your current db structure and queries, and see if we can work out how to make them faster

Comment: For example, if I have only one multivalued custom field the query would be: SELECT `subscribers`.`email_address`, `subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`, `t1`.`value` AS `Languages` FROM `subscribers` LEFT JOIN (SELECT subscriber_id, field_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '|') AS value FROM subscribers_multivalued WHERE field_id=37 GROUP BY subscriber_id, field_id) AS `t1` ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id AND t1.field_id=37 WHERE (list_id=49) AND (state=1)

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your code into a single function that reads the data for the N<sup>th</sup> line, processes it, outputs that line without output buffering, and the discards all temporary data. Call that function repeatedly. This should reduce your memory usage to only what is needed on a given line, instead of handling all lines together.

Once this is done, you can extend it to read an arbitrary number of lines at the same time, in order to tweak the memory usage and the performance tradeoff this involves.

Comment: It's not very easy, I have take data from several tables. In one tables I store entity, in others custom attributes (some of them can be multivalue). It looked rather suprising the several megabytes for the database in PHP array turns into huge amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to prevent supeflous grouping it's possible to use DISTINCT in aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT `subscribers`.`email_address`, `subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Colors, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.value SEPARATOR '|') AS Languages
FROM `subscribers`
LEFT JOIN `subscribers_multivalued` AS `t1` ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t1.subscriber_id AND t1.field_id=49
LEFT JOIN `subscribers_multivalued` AS `t2` ON subscribers.subscriber_id=t2.subscriber_id AND t2.field_id=48
WHERE (list_id=63)
GROUP BY `subscribers`.`email_address`, `subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`
```

Answer (score 0):

> So exporting even several megabytes of data, require hundreds megabytes of memory in php script. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Since [another post asking that same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12663544) got marked as a duplicate of this, I'll give an answer to that part of your question without regard to all the other specific details you asked.

## Row-based processing in PHP

In order to reduce the amount of memory PHP requires at any time, you can fetch rows from the MySQL server one at a time, and pass them on to the client browser (or some file on the server) without buffering.

To fetch rows one at a time, add `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` as the resultmode parameter to the [`mysqli::query`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) call in order to iterate over the results one row at a time, without transferring them all to PHP in one bunch. See also the documentation for [`mysqli::use-result`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php).

Make sure you're not using [PHP output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), so that you won't need memory for the whole document. If you write the content to a file on the server (e.g. using [`fwrite`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)), you can later on pass that file to the client using [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) or similar. You may use the file as a cache, in case you need to transfer the same result several times.

## MySQL writing to file

If you have the [`FILE` privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file), then you can issue a [`SELECT … INTO OUTFILE …`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) query to have the MySQL server write the result directly to some (temporary) file on the server.

You can then either [redirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.4) the client to that file so that the web server will serve that as a plain static file, or you can pass the content to the client yourself using [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). The latter has the benefit that you can [remove](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) the file immediately after it has been passed to the client, in cases where you know you won't need it again.