# Export large database to file without mysqldump, low memory footprint

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [memory usage export from database to csv in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309287/memory-usage-export-from-database-to-csv-in-php)

I am exporting a large database and wanted to know the best way to make it have a low memory footprint.

I realize that I must do this in cycles that have a time limit and use low memory, fetching say 100 rows at a time and saving the information to the file then redirect to start a new cycle starting from where it finished on the previous cycle.

I am wondering whats the best way buffer the data to file and not run out of memory, at present the script gets all data as a string then saves to file when it has finished getting all rows from the database. Some times it runs out of memory, hence the need to fix.

Do I use fwrite() on the data fetched from the database instead of putting into a var or use a temp file? If I use a temp file when do I merge/rename into the backup file?

Basically what is the best way for the script to export the database data into a file without getting the error "Fatal Error: PHP Allowed Memory Size Exhausted"?

```
    function backup_tables($host, $user, $pass, $db, $tables = '*')
    {
            set_time_limit(0);

            $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass, $db);
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }

            $return = '';

            $return .= "--\n";
            $return .= "-- Database: `$db`\n";
            $return .= "--\n\n";
            $return .= "-- --------------------------------------------------------\n\n";

            $numtypes = array(
                'tinyint', 
                'smallint',
                'mediumint',
                'int',
                'bigint',
                'float',
                'double',
                'decimal',
                'real'
            );

            // get all of the tables
            if ($tables == '*')
            {
                    $tables = array();
                    $result = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES');
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_row())
                    {
                            $tables[] = $row[0];
                    }

                    $result->close();
            }
            else
            {
                    $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
            }

            for ($z = 0; $z == 0; $z++)
            {
                echo $z.'<br>';

            // cycle through tables
            foreach ($tables as $table)
            {
                    //
                    $typesarr = array();
                    $result = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `".$table."`");

                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                            $typesarr[] = $row;
                    }
                    $result->close();

                    #echo '<h2>'.$table.'</h2>';
                    #print("<pre>" . print_r($typesarr, true). "</pre>");

                    // table structure dump
                    $return .= "--\n";
                    $return .= "-- Table structure for table `$table`\n";
                    $return .= "--\n\n";                        
                    $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `'.$table.'`;'."\n\n";
                    $result = $mysqli->query("SHOW CREATE TABLE `".$table."`");
                    $row = $result->fetch_array();
                    $return.= $row[1].";\n\n";
                    $result->close();

                    // table data dump
                    $return .= "--\n";
                    $return .= "-- Dumping data for table `$table`\n";
                    $return .= "--\n\n";

                    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `".$table."`");
                    $num_fields = $result->field_count;

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                    {
                            // put field names in array and into sql insert for dump
                            $fields_str = '';
                            $fields =  array();
                            $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();

                            foreach ($finfo as $val)
                            {
                                    $fields_str .= '`'.$val->name.'`, ';
                                    $fields[] = $val->name;
                            }                                

                            $fields_str = '('.rtrim($fields_str, ', ').')';
                            $return.= 'INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` '.$fields_str.' VALUES'."\n";

                            // cycle through fields and check if int for later use
                            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
                            {
                                    // strip brackets from type
                                    $acttype = trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $typesarr[$i]['Type']));
                                    $acttype = explode(' ', $acttype);

                                    // build array, is field int or not
                                    if (is_numeric(array_search($acttype[0], $numtypes)))
                                    {
                                            $numflag[$i] = 1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            $numflag[$i] = 0;        
                                    }
                            }
                    }  

                    $x = 0;
                    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

                    // cycle through table rows
                    while($row = $result->fetch_row())
                    {
                            $x++;

                            // cycle through rows fields
                            for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
                            {          
                                    if (isset($row[$j]) and $j === 0) { $return .= '('; }

                                    // field data has value or not NULL
                                    if (isset($row[$j]))
                                    { 
                                            // field data dump (INT)
                                            if ($numflag[$j]==1)
                                            {
                                                    #echo '(INT) '. $fields[$j].' = '.$row[$j].'<br>';
                                                    $return.= $mysqli->real_escape_string($row[$j]);
                                            } 
                                            else
                                            {
                                                    // field data dump values (empty string, NULL and INT)
                                                    $return.= "'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($row[$j])."'";
                                                    #echo $fields[$j]." = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($row[$j])."'<br>";
                                            }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            // field data dump (NULL)
                                            if (is_null($row[$j]))
                                            {
                                                    $row[$j] = 'NULL';
                                                    #echo '(NULL) '. $fields[$j].' = '.$row[$j].'<br>';
                                                    $return.= $row[$j]; 
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                    // field data dump (empty string)
                                                    $return.= "''";
                                            }
                                    }

                                    if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ', '; }
                            }

                            if ($x<$num_rows) { $return.= "),\n"; } else { $return .= ");\n"; }

                            #echo '<br>';
                    }
                    #echo 'Rows: '.$rows.'<br>';
                    #echo 'Iterations: '.$x.'<br>';
                    $return.="\n-- --------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
            }

            }

            $result->close();

            //save file
            $handle = fopen('/db-backup-'.time().'.sql','a');
            fwrite($handle,$return);
            fclose($handle);
    }
```

Examples welcome

Comment: [`SELECT […] INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/backup'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)

Comment: When posting questions (or answer for that matter) also include the **relevant** code on SO. This way it will still be here when the link goed down.

Comment: @Gordon will the export very large databases no problem, I dont want it to still run out of memory, also will INTO OUTFILE include DROP/CREATE

Comment: @arbme not it will not include DROP/CREATE. It will simply write all the data you SELECTed into the specified file. This will not use up any of PHP's memory because it all happens on the mysql server.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks very much and this would not cause any mysql to run out of memory?

Comment: @arbme it would not cause "Fatal Error: PHP Allowed Memory Size Exhausted" because the data is never pulled into PHP's memory space.

Comment: Why not `mysqldump`? It makes no sense to reimplement the wheel, as building an actually workable SQL dump of a database has some non-trivial dependency implications.

Comment: @lanzz hosting does not allow mysqldump :(

Comment: @abme No, I dont think you would get an error from mysql from this. Although I am not entirely sure. Just delete the Q to keep your 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` as the `resultmode` parameter to the [`mysqli::query`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) call in order to iterate over the results one row at a time, without transferring them all to PHP in one bunch. See also the documentation for [`mysqli::use-result`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php).

Write each line directly to the output file, avoiding the `$result` variable. Combined with the above, this can lead to each row being fetched from the server and written to file, so PHP won't have to store more than one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of `mysqldump` by default have `--opt` enabled, which includes `--quick` which in turns indicates that rows are fetched one at a time, without buffering the whole table in memory. So the memory footprint of `mysqldump` already should be pretty low.

Are you sure that there are actually any problems when using `mysqldump`? If so, how do they manifest? Is `mysqldump` out of memory, or is it the mysql server, or something else entirely?

Comment: I wish I could use mysqldump, cant use system() etc

Comment: @arbme, perhaps you should explicitely say so in your question.

Comment: mysqldump does not release memory after backup which increases my CPU to 90%